# Where are keyboard text shortcuts stored in Mac OS X

Tags: osx-yosemite

I’m writing an AppleScript which interfaces with the “System Preferences > Keyboard > Text” information and I wanted to know where the actual properties are being stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~/Library/Dictionaries/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/

In that folder are multiple folders containing different databases. These are not directly editable .txt files but rather .db files. Though you can copy and paste the folders from a different Mac and it will expand your own text shortcuts database.

Comment: Is it possible to edit these manually?

Answer (score 3):

Search `~/Library/Dictionaries/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/` for `UserDictionary.db`. Use "DB Browser for SQLite" app to view the .db file. Shortcuts are in the `ZUSERDICTIONARYENTRY` table, `ZPHRASE` and `ZSHORTCUT` are the columns you need.

Comment: My text replacements disappeared after upgrading iOS and macOS. I was able to restore them from this file in Time Machine, and your suggestion of DB Browser app helped confirm I found the right set. Thanks.